How to group data in the Google Big Query by date (daily, monthly, and yearly)
I prepared the SQL query to select data grouped by date and source. Thanks to that I know, that on a given day I had X customer's requests from the source_a and Y from source_b and Z form source_c.
The query is:
SELECT
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(CAST(JSON_VALUE(DATA, '$.createdAt') AS INT64) / 1000 AS INT64))) AS date,
  JSON_VALUE(DATA, '$.source') AS source,
  COUNT(*) AS source_request_count
FROM `my_big_query_table`
GROUP BY
  date, source
ORDER BY date DESC

The output is:



date
source
source_request_count




2024-10-03
source_a
10


2024-10-03
source_b
5


2024-10-03
source_c
7


2024-10-02
source_a
9


2024-10-02
source_c
6



Question:
I'd like to ask, how to rebuild the query to group data by source and month (or year). For instance, to return values in January 2024?
Expected output:



date
source
source_request_count




Jun-24
source_a
100


Jun-24
source_b
50


Jun-24
source_c
70


Feb-24
source_a
90


Feb-24
source_c
60



Thank you for your help.

Ok, the solution is formatting the timestamp using FORMAT_TIMESTAMP function and then just order descending.
The query I have looked for is:
SELECT
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(CAST(JSON_VALUE(DATA, '$.createdAt') AS INT64) / 1000 AS INT64))) AS month,
  JSON_VALUE(DATA, '$.source') AS source,
  COUNT(*) AS source_request_count
FROM `my_big_query_table`
GROUP BY
  month, source
ORDER BY month DESC;

